# How can I add ComponentGroupRefs to a feature automatically after generating fragments with heat.exe

Tags: wix

I have a requirement to dynamically create an installer using for a list of files contained in a text file.

The file list contains individual files from many different directories, and is prone to change on a fairly regular basis. I am attempting to create an installer that will not need to be updated each time a new version of the file list is created.

So far I am calling heat.exe from the command line inside a cmd script, where I use a for loop to iterate through the file list, running a heat command against each file to create a fragment of the component.

```
FOR /F "delims=;"  %%a IN (FileList.txt) DO (heat.exe file "%%a" -cg ComponentGroupName -gg -g1 -sfrag -dr DirectoryName %%~da -out "%~dp0%%~na.wxs")
```

*Obviously this bit of code will give each ComponentGroup the same name, which poses an issue, but I can solve that by using the name of the file inside the component group name when I get around to it.*

The bit I am struggling with is how to add the name of the component group to a feature element inside my Project.wsx file.

I have read through the  [Wix Toolset Documentation Manual](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/) and the relevant sections in the book [WiX 3.6: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML](https://www.amazon.co.uk/WiX-3-6-Developers-Windows-Installer/dp/1782160426/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1496766614&sr=8-1&keywords=wix%203.6%3A) and cannot find out how to do this.

I appreciate that I could use some form of text replacement to do this, but I was hoping there was something built into the Wix Toolset as I cant be the first person with the need to dynamically create heat generated components.

Comment: You could generate a WXS file that contains a "main" component group that will reference all the heat-generated component groups. Reference this "main" component group in the feature element of your "project.wxs" file. This way you don't have to change your "project.wxs" all the time.

Comment: If you harvest a directory with heat you get a component group that includes all the harvested components. Simply reference that

Comment: im not able to harvest a directory as there are other files contained in the directory that I don't want to include in the installer.

Comment: If I was to have a 'main' component group that referenced the heat generated componentGroups, I would still have the issue of how to create this 'main' componentGroup.
I cant see how to reference the componentgroup ids of the heat generated component groups, without some sort of manual process of creating componentgrouprefs inside either a 'main' component group, or as individual entries within a feature.
Its this manual task that im trying to automate, either as part of the call to heat, or using some other part of the Wix Toolset.
Thanks

Comment: One technique is to create a folder structure to harvest from. Another is to remove unwanted components (identified through partial paths, for example) by passing heat an XSL transform to filter its output. You can use both, of course. (Sometimes problems are solved by adjusting the division of labor between app devs and installer devs or app projects and installer projects.)

Comment: Re-harvesting your generated wax file to create on component group is pretty easy with PowerShell and other .NET languages and somewhat easy within MSBuild. What would fit well in your project?

Answer (score 2):

Ive come up with an acceptable solution to my issue. 
What im doing is running a cmd file to generate the heat components. Each of these components is stored in its own componentGroup, identified by the id "ComponentGroup" + the iterative counter of the file in the list of files.

After the heat components have been generated, I then create a further ComponenGroup in a separate wxs file, which contains ComponentGroupRefs to each of the ComponentGroups created by heat.

As this ComponentGroup is created from the cmd file and I know the Id of, I am able to reference it in my feature.

```
    @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a count = 0
FOR /F "delims=;" %%a IN (FileList.txt) DO (
set /a count=count+1
heat.exe file "%%a" -cg "ComponentGroup!count!" -gg -g1 -sfrag -dr NotSureWhatGoesHereYet %%~da -out "%~dp0%%~na.wxs" 
)

(
echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?^>
echo ^<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"^>
echo      ^<Fragment^>
echo          ^<ComponentGroup Id="ComponentGroup"^>
) > test.wxs

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,%count%) DO (
  echo              ^<ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroup%%i" /^> >> Components.wxs
)

(
echo          ^</ComponentGroup^>
echo     ^</Fragment^>
echo ^</Wix^> 
) >> Components.wxs
```

Thanks for the responses guys. @TomBlodget I took inspiration from your first answer. Thanks for your time